# Permission for a Single Page on Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online

We have one page on our SharePoint site that I would like to share with a user group and would only like that page tobe viewable to them. Is it possible for only that page to show up for the group or does everything have to be viewable to them?

The usergroup only has a read permission.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the library where the page is stored you can break permissions inheritance on the page, and only give the group that your users are in access to read the page.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be achieved. Right click the file and choose "share", enter the group name. You could choose view or edit permission for the group.

Like this:

[image]